# "Make failed" when installing Imagick on MacOS Monterey with M1 chip

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, laravel-valet, macos-monterey

I use Laravel Valet. I'm trying to install the Image Magick PHP extension (PHP 7.4). I get as far as this:

`pecl install imagick`

And I get the error `make failed`.

I'm on MacOS Monterey with the Apple Silicon M1 chip.

Any tips?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To install `imagick` using `pecl`:

Install `imagemagick`

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Then install `imagick` using `pecl`.

```
pecl install imagick
```

Also, I maintain a brew tap [shivammathur/extensions](https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-extensions) you can use instead. It has pre-compiled commonly used PHP extensions.

Installing imagick on PHP 7.4 using the tap is as simple as:

```
brew tap shivammathur/extensions
brew install imagick@7.4
```

Comment: Your tap seems to have resolved it. Thank you very much!

Comment: So it turns out that in order to use your tap, I have to use `valet use php@7.4 --force` otherwise it uses the old version of PHP and I get deprecation errors. Do you know how I can make it use yours automatically?

Comment: If you have PHP 7.4 installed, you can run `brew upgrade` to make sure it is the latest patch version. To switch to it you can run `brew link --force --overwrite php@7.4`.

If you still have any errors, please create an issue with the details here
https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-extensions/issues

Comment: @ShivamMathur thanks for the tap - got imagemagick on laravel valet M1 sorted!

Comment: works for me with brew its very easy!. ty

Comment: Thanks so much @ShivamMathur, the pecl install did not work for imagick, but your precompiled versions did the trick. I got the same issue as joomkit, on an M1, the pecl install seems to be working, but when using it, it says some characters could not be read. Installing via pecl works for grpc and redis compile sessions for example, but for some reason, not for imagick.

Comment: I also had issues with installing using pecl on M1. I had errors "Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' ... symbol not found in flat namespace".  Your tap worked. In my case I used `brew install imagick@8.0` for PHP 8.0